# How can one test inline snapshots with Jest and Prettier 3.0.0?

Tags: jestjs, prettier

After updating to the latest Jest and Prettier versions, I started receiving the following error when trying to test inline snapshots with Jest (e.g. `expect(xxx).toMatchInlineSnapshot()`):

```
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Jest: Inline Snapshots are not supported when using Prettier 3.0.0 or above.
    See https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration/#prettierpath-string for alternatives.

      at saveInlineSnapshots (node_modules/jest-snapshot/build/InlineSnapshots.js:101:15)
```

When following [the link suggested in the error](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration/#prettierpath-string), it doesn't really give much information with regards to alternatives, but just describes how to change the Prettier library path. I don't believe changing the path will resolve the issue.

So my questions are:

1. How can one test inline snapshots with Prettier 3.0.0?
2. If Prettier 3.0.0 is not supported, is this something they're
   planning on adding or are they planning on adding alternatives?

Apologies if these questions have already been answered, but I wasn't able to find any information around it in the libraries' documentation.

Here are the relevant library versions:

```
"jest": "^29.6.2",
"prettier": "^3.0.0",
```

Comment: Did you read https://github.com/jestjs/jest/issues/14305? Or you could just revert Prettier to v2.

Answer (score 3):

The documentation now includes this information under [`prettierpath` [string]](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration/#prettierpath-string):

> Prettier version 3 is not supported!
>
> ---
>
> You can either pass `prettierPath: null` in your config to disable
> using prettier if you don't need it, or use v2 of Prettier solely for
> Jest.
>
> `package.json`
>
> ```json
> {
>   "devDependencies": {
>     "prettier-2": "npm:prettier@^2"
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> ```js
> /** @type {import('jest').Config} */
> const config = {
>   prettierPath: require.resolve('prettier-2'),
> };
>
> module.exports = config;
> ```
>
> We hope to support Prettier v3 seamlessly out of the box in a future
> version of Jest. See
> [this](https://github.com/jestjs/jest/issues/14305) tracking issue.

---

As commented below by [fgblomqvist](https://stackoverflow.com/users/998919/fgblomqvist) the "future version of Jest" mentioned above will be v30; support for Prettier 3 arrived in [`v30.0.0-alpha.1`](https://github.com/jestjs/jest/releases/tag/v30.0.0-alpha.1).

Comment: Prettier 3 will be supported in [Jest 30](https://github.com/jestjs/jest/releases/tag/v30.0.0-alpha.1).